# Windows 10 is saying a valid key "id_rsa" is using invalid format

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I brought a pair of keys from a linux debian machine which is working fine. But, when I tried it on a windows 10 machine using ssh service by power shell it is not working, the error message starts with: 'key_load_public: No such file or directory' and later 'Load key "C:\Users\clebe/.ssh/id_rsa": invalid format'. The right private key is the id_rsa file on .ssh folder

```
PS C:\Users\clebe> ssh cleber@X.X.X.X -vvv
OpenSSH_7.5p1, without OpenSSL
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:./ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "X.X.X.X" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to X.X.X.X [X.X.X.X] port 22.
debug3: socket:480, socktype:1, io:00000190FC669EA0, fd:3
debug1: Connection established.
key_load_public: invalid format
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/id_dsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/id_dsa.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/id_dsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/id_dsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/id_ed25519 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to X.X.X.X:22 as 'cleber'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from X.X.X.X
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:./ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:./ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:N60fODxHIhAgCZNIOKI07KlqsHOK5XN3ENQDZaCZXWM
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from X.X.X.X
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:./ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:./ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: Host 'X.X.X.X' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug3: socket:0, socktype:1, io:00000190FC66A000, fd:4
debug3: close - io:00000190FC66A000, type:2, fd:4, table_index:4
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/id_rsa (0000000000000000)
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/id_dsa (0000000000000000)
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0000000000000000)
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: open - handle:000000000000021C, io:00000190FC669A80, fd:4
debug3: close - io:00000190FC669A80, type:2, fd:4, table_index:4
Load key "C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/id_rsa": invalid format
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: GetFileAttributesExW with last error 2
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: GetFileAttributesExW with last error 2
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\clebe/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
cleber@X.X.X.X: Permission denied (publickey).
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

`OpenSSH_7.5p1, without OpenSSL`

This version/copy of OpenSSH is compiled **without OpenSSL**, an option which causes *many* features to not work, among them RSA keypairs. Notice

```
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519
```

lists *only* ed25519, and the although KEXINIT doesn't directly control *client* authentication in the protocol the same limitation applies there.
It would be nice if OpenSSH gave a more specific error message; you could file a bug report if you care enough.

Is this the version that came with Windows or did you install (or build) it yourself? I vaguely recall that in 2018 WSL wasn't fully baked, although I didn't use it and didn't follow the details. I know the W10 machine I bought in late *2019* came with
`OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5` which *does* support RSA (and DSS, although that's disabled by default as per upstream policy since IIRC 7.0). (If you don't know, LibreSSL is a fork of OpenSSL and for this purpose functionally equivalent.)

Answer (score 0):

`Invalid Format` of `id_rsa` in Windows 10, when using `ssh.exe` from `OpenSSH` e.g.

```
C:\Users\tong> C:\"Program Files"\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe -V
OpenSSH_9.2p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1t  7 Feb 2023
```

Make sure the `id_rsa` file is in `LF`, line feed break line (not `CRLF`). And one blank line at the end of the file is a must.

It can be checked/changed using `VS Code`, open the file at lower right shows the break line format (`LF or CRLF`). Most important thing is the last *blank* new line, at line number 39. see image.

Then the file should be a valid for the `ssh`.
Note this case would not occur when using `Microsoft ssh`.

[image]